# Fetching the kernel parameters passed via bootloader (grub)

Tags: linux-kernel, parameter-passing, init, bootloader

How can be accessed kernel parameters (passed via `Grub`) in `initramfs`'s init script?
I have idea to introduce some param and use use it init like `if(myparam == 0) {} else {}`

Answer (score 2):

The data you are looking for could be found in `/proc/cmdline`